# What is the correct syntax for labels for Jenkins agent nodes?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I am configuring Linux agent node in Jenkins. What is the correct syntax (separator and escaping) for multiple labels here?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English help says clearly what to write in this field.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

You should separate labels with [whitespaces](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/jenkins-2.0-rc-1/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Label.java#L585). If a label contains a space you should quote it (single and double quotes are ok): E.g `slave 'single quotes' "double quotes" "1970's" '1980\'s'` results in these set of labels:

[image]